# assembler write to file problem

Tags: file-io, assembly

```
dseg segment
FileName db "hex.txt$"
dseg ends
cseg seg..
...
wrFile proc
 push ax bx cx dx
 mov ax,3D00h
 mov dx, offset fileName
 int 21h
 mov bx,ax
 mov cx,10*type scores
 mov dx,offset highscoresnum
 mov ah,40h
 int 21h
 mov dx,offset highscoresdate
 mov ah,40h
 int 21h
 mov ah,3eh
 int 21h
 pop dx cx bx ax
 ret
wrFile endp
```

at the first int 21h (ah=3dH) CF is not cleared and AX turns to 2h.
in the net it's written that AX holds the error code, but i couldn't find it. what do i do wrong?

Comment: `push ax bx cx dx`? What assembler are you using for that?

Comment: 8086,that's what they teach us at school

Comment: eden, I understand the mnemonics, I've just never seen an assembler that lets you push or pop more than one register at a time. That's not doable in standard x86 so I'm assuming the assembler itself is turning that into `push ax ; push bx ; ...` which is a nice feature. Hence my question - I wanted to look into the actual assembler product.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're getting a "file not found" error, because the `INT 21h` functions that use file or path names generally require them to be terminated with a zero byte, not a `'$'`.

Comment: Correct. According to this: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2779.htm it's an ASCIZ string, so it's zero terminated.